# How to import code from other html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My point is to import Text from **b.html** to store inside **div id="content"** so the Javascripts should be work like this `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "whole Text/HTML from b.html";`

Original code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#content").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
</head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="content" data-uid="1"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

This simple question seems to be duplicated but I have no idea why the code I copied is not working. I got the error in console, but *don't know if my code was correct or not.* I still need more explain about them.
"**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/makemeapp/b.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**"

**The other related question is**, how to link to that div by using data-uid="1"?(see Original code) For example, if I want to change text inside by linking to id="content" , I use `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "...";`, then how can I change text inside by linking to data-uid ?

I really appreciate all replies.
Sorry for English and for being very newbie.
I had tried my best to search for them.

Comment: You're opening the file without a proper webserver, that's why it uses a `file://` protocol. You need to use the webserver you've already installed, assuming the folder `/xampp` actually holds XAMPP.

Comment: @Mes: It's not generally acceptable to ask more than one question per post.  If you have 2 questions you should post them separately.

Comment: The reason your XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/makemeapp/testlayout2.html is because cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, my question is clear now. So I just learned that kind of things is called "protocal". Sorry for having 2 questions then. The question 2 seems to be very easy, so it must have been answered somewhere but I can't find it. So, I was too afraid of spamming duplicated questions. :( Any external link  to answer my question is appreciated. Thank you everyone again. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it works

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('b.html', function(data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend to clear the content `$("#content").html('')` before loading the new content, as the previous content would display while AJAX works.

Answer (score 0):

Read the content of `child.htm` and `parent.htm`

**Note:** This works if:

- Both pages are on the same domain
- Both are online (i.e. a website or a local server)

child.htm

```html
<style>
  * {color:red;}
</style>
<h1>child.html</h1>
<p>This is the HTML that needs to be imported to target page</p>
<p>The optimal structure of this page has no  &lt;html&gt; and no  &lt;head&gt;
</p>
<div></div>
<script>
  var x = document.querySelector('div');
  x.innerHTML = "This is generated dynamically"
</script>
```

parent.htm

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>parent.htm</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <p>This is the target page.</p>
  <p>For every piece of external HTML you want imported, place an empty div an this page with the attribute data-xmh="nameOfPage.html"</p>
  <div data-xmh="child.htm"></div>

  <script>
    function xmHTMLInclude() {
      var ele, i, tgt, file, xmHttp;
      ele = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].getAttribute("data-xmh")) {
          tgt = ele[i].cloneNode(false);
          file = ele[i].getAttribute("data-xmh");
          xmHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmHttp.readyState == 4 && xmHttp.status == 200) {
              tgt.removeAttribute("data-xmh");
              tgt.innerHTML = xmHttp.responseText;
              ele[i].parentNode.replaceChild(tgt, ele[i]);
              xmHTMLInclude();
            }
          }
          xmHttp.open("GET", file, true);
          xmHttp.send();
          return;
        }
      }
    };

    /*~~~~ Usage

    (function () {
     xmHTMLInclude();
    });

    Target element must have a data-xmh attribute
    <div data-xmh="frag.htm"></div>
    */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This kind is interesting, but I can't understand it much. Well, is there any easier code or 1 line of code to refer to data-* like getElementById. ?

Comment: Try Uday's answer, maybe it's that simple.

Comment: His answer works fine. But he can link only with id, I would like it to link by data-uid like how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/makemeapp/testlayout2.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

You are running it from the `file:///` protocol. You have to start a local webserver, and then you can make the request.

If you have Python installed, you can run this command in `C:/xampp/htdocs/makemeapp/` to start a simple webserver.

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Then browse to `http://localhost:8080/testlayout2.html`, and your script will work.